# Does NCBI's blast API block my IP?

Tags: blast, phylogenetics

I am trying to run a `blatn` command from both my laptop and within a google colab notebook. I am not sure why, but this command runs properly once and then, on the second execution, it gets stuck for hours without a reply.

Is it possible that NCBI blocks my IP? I've tried also to run `web_blast.pl` and this didn't work either.

biopython:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

fasta = '>seq0\n'+'AACCACCTGACGGGCTCTGT'
blast_res = NCBIWWW.qblast('blastn', 'nt', fasta)
print(blast_res.read())
```

`web_blast.pl` command:

`web_blast.pl blastn nt input.fa > blast.out`

Note, if this is due to throttling by NCBI, I am not sure how do they expect people to query their web service if they block you after one call.

Comment: If you have a high usage department might explain it. Try via your own ip

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [User Guide](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=DeveloperInfo):

> The NCBI BLAST servers are a shared resource. We give priority to
> interactive users. In order to ensure availability of the service to
> the entire community, we may limit searches for some high volume
> users. Interactive users of the NCBI webpages through a web browser
> should not encounter problems. We will move searches of users who
> submit more than 100 searches in a 24 hour period to a slower queue,
> or, in extreme cases, will block the requests. To avoid problems, API
> users should comply with the following guidelines:
>
> 1. Do not contact the server more often than once every 10 seconds.
> 2. Do not poll for any single RID more often than once a minute.
> 3. Use the URL parameter email and tool, so that the NCBI can contact you
>    if there is a problem.
> 4. Run scripts weekends or between 9 pm and 5 am Eastern time on weekdays
>    if more than 50 searches will be submitted.